# Change format of DateTime without converting to string

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and I have Datetime variable like:

```
DateTime startingDate
```

value = `8/8/2018 4:16:18 PM`

I want value like `8/8/2018`, how can I just drop hours minutes seconds and `PM`value without converting to string? because I'm forced DateTime type for another thing.

Comment: Have you tried `startingDate.Date`?

Comment: The _"format"_ is only useful for converting `DateTime` to `string`. Internaly, there is no _"format"_ in `DateTime`

Comment: `DateTime` is a `struct`, there is no specified date format (it contains properties to store date & time elements instead). The specific format only apply when used in string representation.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: I completely agree that there's no format data within `DateTime`, but the fact that it's a struct is irrelevant to that. It could still be a struct but also contain a reference to a format string, or it could be a class but still *not* have any formatting information.

Comment: Use following : startingDate = startingDate.Date.  The DateTime object is store as a number as two parts 1) The number of days from 1/1/01 2) The factional part of the day like 6AM = 6/24.  The Date property only uses the integer part of the Date and rounds the date to midnight at the beginning of the day.

Answer (score 1):

In C# (as in many other languages) there is no separate `Date` and `Time`, it's just `DateTime`. Regardless of that though, there are many use cases where you only need a date. In C# it's assumed that if you just need `8/8/2018` then in reality you are working with `8/8/2018 0:00:00.000`.

If you need to work with just the Date but still keep it as a DateTime, then the most straightfoward method is to use `.Date` (i.e. `startingDate.Date`). This can get a little confusing since the default `.ToString()` for `DateTime` represents it (in whatever is the cultural norm for your computer) as Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute:Second AM/PM.

Also, for further clarification, `DateTime` is an object that has a variety of different properties (`Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second` etc), so thinking of it having a "format" is incorrect. It's a collection of things that together make up a Date and/or Time.

Comment: Note that C# as a language doesn't care about this at all. It's only a matter of what the .NET framework provides. There are other libraries available for .NET which *do* provide separate date/time/date-time/date-time-zone etc types.